# Create a json array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying the create the following:

```
[
    {
        category: "fruity",
        products: [
            {
                description : "Apple",
                price : 12,99
            },
            {
                description : "Peach",
                price : 17,99
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        category: "Cakes",
        products: [
            {
                description : "Cake one",
                price : 12,99
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I don't seem to get the nested array right. I appreciate some help.

Comment: What data? We just see the JSON you want.

Comment: What are you even asking? JavaScript has native JSON support. Setting that as a variable does exactly what you want.

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON array, there are Javascript Arrays, and then there is JSON representing Javascript arrays. If you are putting data into an array then all you need to get the JSON is to call JSON.stringify() on your array. If you are needing some type of restructuring, then you are going to need to provide the proper information, like what the structure is currently

Comment: @jhpratt unless it won't be JSON but an array literal.

Comment: @PHPglue, yep. I want to provide the data in that format to my app. I'm working on it since morning and I can't get it.

Comment: @CélioGarcia so what kind of help are you seeking?

Comment: @zerkms I'm facing a dificult to put my dataset in this format

Comment: @CélioGarcia okay, and what kind of help are you looking for?

Comment: @PatrickEvans, You maybe right, I'll try to do it

Comment: What we have here is a failure to communicate....  I think the OP is asking how to convert data from a database to JSON format.

Comment: If you replace the `,` with `.` in the numbers (`12,99 -> 12.99`), you can copy and paste what you wrote and put it directly into your JavaScript source code. It will create an array of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is due to the extra commas present in your price values:
12,99 should be 12.99

This can be confusing for people from locales who traditionally separate decimals using commas such as in French.